# Getting List of Hostname/IP from ESXi using Managed Object Browser (MOB)

Tags: rest, api, soap, vmware

Is it possible to get a list of IPs/Hostnames of Virtual Machines on my ESXi using a "simple" HTTP-Request against https:///mob, insead of using the "VMware vSphere SDK for Perl"

Answer (score 1):

Not in a singular HTTP-Request, it will be multiple step. You'll have to pull the list of VirtualMachine objects then, for each VM object, reference the 'GuestInfo' data object, and finally either the hostname and/or ipAddress property: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-5/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.vm.GuestInfo.html

Note, those two properties are being gathered from VMware Tools so if you have a system that isn't running VMware Tools, it's likely to be blank.

Comment: Could you share the first https-request?